# Identifying the code from a warning in the kernel log

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, uclinux

while booting my linux kernel I am getting the log file like this what causing this and how to solve..?

```
------------[ cut here ]------------
WARNING: at drivers/gpio/gpiolib.c:1423 0xa02147ab()
Modules linked in:
Backtrace: no frame pointer
 ---[ end trace ccc3de96c2b87179 ]---
------------[ cut here ]------------
WARNING: at drivers/gpio/gpiolib.c:1423 0xa02147ab()
Modules linked in:
Backtrace: no frame pointer
---[ end trace ccc3de96c2b8717a ]---
------------[ cut here ]------------
WARNING: at drivers/gpio/gpiolib.c:1423 0xa02147ab()
Modules linked in:
Backtrace: no frame pointer
---[ end trace ccc3de96c2b8717b ]---
ds3232 0-0068: rtc core: registered ds3232 as rtc0
i2c-gpio i2c-gpio.0: using pins 27 (SDA) and 28 (SCL)
```

Comment: This question is not programming - it belongs on Serverfault.

Comment: Linux kernel version and arch please...

Comment: kernel version 2.6.33

Answer (score 1):

Pay close attention to the following line in the kernel log :
`WARNING: at drivers/gpio/gpiolib.c:1423 0xa02147ab()`

This means that this print is triggered from line number `1423` of the file `drivers/gpio/gpiolib.c`

---

**`WARN_ON()`** triggered from [**drivers/gpio/gpiolib.c:1423**](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/gpio/gpiolib.c?v=2.6.33#L1418) in the Linux Kernel.

```
int __gpio_get_value(unsigned gpio)
{
        struct gpio_chip        *chip;

        chip = gpio_to_chip(gpio);
        WARN_ON(extra_checks && chip->can_sleep);
        return chip->get ? chip->get(chip, gpio - chip->base) : 0;
}
```

<sub>**NOTE** : The above code is (v2.6.33 on arch=x86). Before proceeding with the above analysis, confirm that you are indeed running Linux Kernel v2.6.33 on x86 hardware. Line numbers change with kernel versions. You may have co-incidentally hit upon a `WARN_ON()` in a different function on the same line in a different kernel version.</sub>

---

**Update** :

Since this issue is caused while communicating with the RTC-DS3232 peripheral (which is otherwise working fine) we can disable the warnings.

One way to do this is to disable `CONFIG_DEBUG` in the Linux kernel build configuration. This in turn disables `extra_checks` within the gpio driver.

Alternately one can override the definition of `extra_checks` at **[drivers/gpio/gpiolib.c:34](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/gpio/gpiolib.c?id=v2.6.33#n27)** as follows

```
/* When debugging, extend minimal trust to callers and platform code.
 * Also emit diagnostic messages that may help initial bringup, when
 * board setup or driver bugs are most common.
 *
 * Otherwise, minimize overhead in what may be bitbanging codepaths.
 */
#ifdef  DEBUG
#define extra_checks    1
#else
#define extra_checks    0
#endif

/* override extra_checks irrespective of debug-mode */
#define extra_checks    0
```

Comment: I have found this in drivers/gpio/gpiolib.c and the line:1423 I am not getting exact scenario what causing this on boot up..? any other possible clues to solve this issue

Comment: What device are you testing this on? Can you post the complete kernel log from boot?...

Comment: I am binding an RTC Ds3232 with i2c and testing this on lpc1788 cortex m3. its looks by kernel boot log my device is registered with kernel,and I can test my device working by getting in to /sys/device/platform/i2c-gpio.0/i2c-0/0-0068/rtc/rtc0# cat date.    when I executed cat date it will show warning same as i mention in my question followed by date.

Comment: Ok. So essentially some function within `drivers/rtc/rtc-ds3232.c` that does I/O is triggering `gpio_get_value()` which in turn is issuing the warning. One reason for this would be if you are bit-banging GPIOs to communicate with RTC-DS3232. Is this the case?

Comment: yes am using GPIO-based bitbanging I2C, is i am going with right way...?

Comment: is "#define extra_checks    0" will not affect for my external device working..?

Comment: You should be fine disabling the `extra_checks` as it appears to be just for debugging. Ensure that your date/time settings are being properly read from and written to the RTC before moving on.

Comment: I can read the rtc date and time at the following path "/sys/device/platform/i2c-gpio.0/i2c-0/0-0068/rtc/rtc0#" by cat command since I can only read at that path. can I use /dev/rtc/ for writing/reading in rtc by using system calls..?

Comment: As far as the verifying i2c using gpio is concerned, a successful read is enough to indicate that it is working properly.